# PHP code is not running before loop

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop, substr

```
<?php
$date = '2017-08-22';
$year = substr($date, 0, 4);
$month = substr($date, 5, 2);
$day = substr($date, 8, 2);
?>

<select>
<?php
for ($i=1; $i < 30; $i++) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if($day === $i){ echo "selected"; }; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
```

the code is not executing because `substr` is not running before the for loop. the select should be selected on day 22 but it is not selecting anything. if i change `$day = 22;`, it works. how can i fix this with the substring?

Comment: what about for `Feb` if date is `2017-02-22` ? do you consider days of month ?

Comment: Also the logic you put to get year, month, days from date is not good. seriously

Comment: @Rishi what do u mean?

Comment: I mean no. of days in all month is not `30`, august is of month `31` days not `30`,

Comment: And if you see your dropdown you get till `29` only , is it right ?

Comment: I provided you the improved code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're doing `===` which is a strict match, since your year/month/day are all strings your day will never work. you need to use `==`

```
'22' === 22; // false
'22' == 22; // true
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

You just change the below line in `<option>` tag inside.

```
if($day === $i)
```

**to**

```
if($day == $i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `var_dump` $day after the `substr` see what happens. Namely, you're using `===` the triple equals comparison which will also check type. `substr` returns a string and you're comparing it to an integer, so the condition is never true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I commented some issue you can use below code to fix

```
<?php
    $date = '2017-08-22';
    $dateSec = strtotime($date);
    $year = date("Y",$dateSec);
    $month = date("m",$dateSec);
    $day = date("d",$dateSec);
    $day_in_month = date("t",$dateSec);
    echo "<select>";
    for ($i=1; $i <= $day_in_month; $i++) {
            $selected = ($day==$i) ? ' selected ':'';
            echo "<option $selected value='$i'>$i</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes when you compare the values through `===` because the values you are comparing does not contain the same data type. `$day` contain the '`string`' data type & the `'$i'` contain the '`int`' data type.

So, for resolving the issue, there are two possible solutions which are as follows, try any one:

Either you use `==` instead of `===`, just like this:

```
if($day == $i)
```

OR

Use `(int)` data type when assigning values to `$day, $month & $year` variable, just like this:

```
$day = (int)substr($date, 8, 2);
```

Hope, this may be helpful to you.